# What's relationship between DSMS and twitter Storm?

Tags: dictionary, stream, apache-storm, reduce

DSMS is data stream management system. 
While Storm is developed by BackType to process stream data seamlessly. 
Is storm a DSMS? 
Or it's just a tool to make DSMS happen. 
Any one can throw me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had never heard of the term DSMS, but looking at the description on wikipedia I think Storm can definitely be said to be a DSMS.

From wikipedia:

> It is similar to a database management system (DBMS) [...] 
>   However, in contrast to a DBMS, a DSMS
>   executes a continuous query that is not only performed once, but is
>   permanently installed.

That sounds exactly what Storm is. Note however in case of Storm, it is usually used in combination with a DBMS. For example, Storm can offer `One-time queries`, `unlimited secondary storage` etc. which the wikipedia says is lacking in DSMS when it's combined with a DBMS.

Comment: yea. It seems they are exactly the same. I read some info somewhere saying that Storm is somewhat CEP, which is similar with DSMS. I was totally messed up by thousands of terminologies. I think you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple

1. DBMS is used for static data, whereas for stream-based data that is continuous in nature DSMS is used
2. SQL is the query language for DBMS hence CQL is query language for DSMS
3. SQL process static queries whereas CQL processes the continuous queries
4. As Oracle is the DBMS, in same manner several DSMS have been made like

   ```
   * STREAM  http://www-db.stanford.edu/stream
   * AURORA http://www.cs.brown.edu/research/aurora/
   ```

So let's talk about Apache Storm. I am doing research in Storm and I think that storm is a query processing engine, not the manager as the management system is that which  can show us the database like oracle  does, yet in Storm , we define topologies to process incoming tuples.